# How do I exclude hidden field from PHP foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a simple form that inserts data into a database using foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) I have a hidden field on the form

```
<input name="isset" type="hidden" value="true" />
```

And i use if(isset($_POST['isset'])) {

I'm trying to work out how to exclude the hidden field from the loop ...?

I've looked at this post but don't understand where i would use if (strpos($key, 'hdn_') == false) // proceed

[How to exclude <input type="hidden"> from a for each loop in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780079/how-to-exclude-input-type-hidden-from-a-for-each-loop-in-php)

any guidance would be appreciated....

Comment: If you really do `foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)` I believe your site will have a great security loophole. It's just a very bad practice.

Comment: @AlvinWong thanks for your help...will look for alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the exact names of keys you want to exclude, [`array_diff_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) is a convenient option:

```
$keysToRemove = array('isset'); // you can add as many as you want
$values = array_diff_key($_POST, array_flip($keysToRemove));

foreach ($values as $k => $v) { ... }
```

However, since `$values` is intended to go into the database you should use a *whitelist* of allowed keys instead of a blacklist. You can do that with [`array_intersect_key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$keysToKeep = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'); // as many as you want
$values = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($keysToKeep));

foreach ($values as $k => $v) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks for you help this is the answer i was looking for .. Does using the foreach loop to insert data create a security risk for the site...?

Comment: @Ledgemonkey: It depends on how you are using the data.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the foreach:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'isset') {
        //code here
    }
}
```

(For what I got from your question)

Or from your array, you can `unset()` the element with the 'isset' array key.